# A UITableView contains a multi-line UILabel. sizeToFit on the label works the first time, but sizes the label incorrectly once the cell is redrawn

Tags: iphone

I log info and size the label like this:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"before: %@, %f", [item valueForKey:@"item"], itemDescLabel.frame.size.width]);
[itemDescLabel sizeToFit];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"after: %@, %f", [item valueForKey:@"item"], itemDescLabel.frame.size.width]);
```

At first it is correct and logs data like

```
before: Nachos, 280.000000
after: Nachos, 265.000000
before: Quesadilla, 232.000000
after: Quesadilla, 229.000000
```

But after scrolling up and down, the labels will obviously be too wide or too narrow, and it logs data like

```
before: Nachos, 0.000000
after: Nachos, 967.000000
before: Quesadilla, 171.000000
after: Quesadilla, 167.000000
```

I use the method suggested by Apple for loading a custom UITableViewCell from a nib, like

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = itemCell;
    itemCell = nil;
}
UILabel *itemDescLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed to reset the size of the frame of the UILabel before calling sizeToFit. Cells are reused to save memory, and apparently sizeToFit sometimes gets screwed up when frame.size is not the original one of the label. I have no idea why this is, but it works.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you loose (one of) the benefit(s) of "sizeToFit" which is to align vertically the label on the top.

Comment: Yes, because the cell is reusable, when you call the sizetofit, will change the label frame,  next time when you reuse it, the small size frame will show not correct. The origin size must big than after sizetofit size.

Comment: This is still an issue in '21!
`label.frame = .zero; label.sizeToFit()`